# Covering Index isn't being used and I don't know why

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

We have this complicated query that I'm trying to make "better" until we move it to pull from a data warehouse. I need a solution that's "good enough" for now and I think I'm about 2-3 indexes away from making that happen. I'm stuck on this part, however.

I'm specifically targeting this part of my Execution Plan:

[image]

That table originally had only 2 indexes: the Clustered PK index (that this shows it doing the Key Lookup on) and another FK index on a column not referenced here. Given that this heavy query always needs these add'l columns (DateForValue [datetime], CurveValue [float], BTUFactor [float], and FuelShrink [float]), I thought a covering index was the obvious solution here to remove the (slow) Key Lookup being performed here. So I added the following covering index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IxFK_TEST_tblPriceRequestCurveValues_ForQuoteViewing] ON [dbo].[tblPriceRequestCurveValues] 
(
    [DateForValue] ASC,
    [CurveValue] ASC,
    [BTUFactor] ASC,
    [FuelShrink] ASC
)
INCLUDE(oid)
```

However, even after adding this index, it seems the query is still doing the Key Lookup.

Am I missing something obvious here or is this the right idea and I just have a problem elsewhere? Note that all statistics and indexes have been refreshed and this isn't THAT highly dynamic of a table but it is approaching ~1M records.

A simplified version of this query, focusing on this table of interest, is as follows. Nothing I removed references the PrimaryTableOfInterest.

```
SELECT * FROM
(query1)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT
    Other table columns,
    PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow.oid, 
    PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow.PriceRequestCurveID, 
    PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow.DateForValue, 
    PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow.CurveValue, 
    PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow.BTUFactor, 
    PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow.FuelShrink
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Other table columns,
            tblPriceRequestCurves.PriceRequestCurveID AS MyForeignKey
        FROM
            tblPriceRequestCurves
            INNER JOIN other stuff unrelated to PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow
        WHERE
            tblPriceRequestCurves.SomeID IS NOT NULL
    )
    INNER JOIN
        tblPriceRequestCurveValues AS PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow
            ON MyForeignKey = PrimaryTableOfInterestForNow.PriceRequestCurveID
WHERE
    tblPriceRequestCurves.SomeID = SomeOtherID
)
UNION ALL
(query3)
ORDER BY xxxx
```

I'm working with each of the 3 portions of the UNION ALL independent of one another and the other two parts are nice and speedy and executing this third of the unions either by itself or in the union performs similarly (i.e. ~30 seconds). So the UNION isn't a factor but I included it just for thoroughness sake.

Comment: Can you show the actual query?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. We have too much IP in this query to share it online.

Comment: Uh, ok, well how about just the where clause? Also it shouldn't be too difficult to mask the proprietary parts, if you really think you've written SQL that nobody else has...

Comment: I'm working on somewhat reproducing/masking this part of the query to post.

Comment: Do you have different query that has [oid] either as an indexed or included value? Just noticed that this operator is seeking based on [oid] from itself. Also, have you blanked out database names in the tooltip you posted? Does this involve cross database queries?

Comment: I only blanked-out DB names but it's all the same DB. I think my posted query answers your question about the [oid] column.

Comment: See minor update to my answer but this is bordering on impossible without the full picture.

Comment: Is `Other table columns` columns from a table other than `tblPriceRequestCurves` or columns from `tblPriceRequestCurves` that aren't already mentioned?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith `Other table columns` that I select are from both `tblPriceRequestCurves` and other tables. I additionally filter/join on 2 more `tblPriceRequestCurves` columns.

Comment: So why are you wanting/expecting a NCIX seek when you know additional columns will be required from the CIX? I'm lost :)

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental (I'm a dev forced to DBA so I know I'm missing some fundamentals). I'm not able to get a Seek instead of a Key Lookup when I need multiple columns here by adding those columns to a new index? That's been my understanding, however right or wrong it is.

Comment: Just because you could, doesn't mean you should :) Or, yes adding all the columns will result in a seek on that index but it isn't necessarily "better". Better is looking likely to be NCIX on `SomeId`, with nothing included.

Comment: Okay, I think you've fully answered my asked question and my non-asked question now. Asked question: Why the Key Lookup and that's because I need to index both the oid and that SomeID columns while including the rest. The unasked question, is that an Index Seek isn't necessarily better than a Key Lookup (the new index including both results in that but no change in execution time). Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Following partial posting of query.

The query hasn't flipped to seek on the suggested NCI because of:

```
WHERE
    tblPriceRequestCurves.SomeID = SomeOtherID
```

Whatever `SomeId` is, it needs to feature in the index. Again, difficult to tell due to the obfuscation but probably as the sole indexed value, everything else `INCLUDE`.

Can't deduce from the query why your doing it this way but the repeated joining to `tblPriceRequestCurves` doesn't make much sense as it stands. Back to my earlier point, its all guesswork without the full picture.

Original:

The seek is on `[oid]`, you've included this rather than make it part of the index. Can't be sure this is optimal for the entire query without seeing the query and execution plan but to turn this particular lookup into the non-clustered index seek you're looking for:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IxFK_TEST_tblPriceRequestCurveValues_ForQuoteViewing] 
ON [dbo].[tblPriceRequestCurveValues] ([oid] ASC)
INCLUDE ([DateForValue], [CurveValue], [BTUFactor], [FuelShrink])
```

Of course, this may be a really bad idea. All we've achieved is swapping a clustered index seek with a non-clustered index seek. Without seeing the full query, its impossible to say whether its the "right" thing to do.

My initial thought is that a clustered index seek (key lookup) for 500 rows in what appears to be an analytic type query is likely to be reasonable. You refer to this lookup as being slow but in what context? Is it just the highest estimated cost operator in the plan?

If ultimately this query is looking at data across a timespan, it may be that DateForValue would be a better choice as the leading key:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IxFK_TEST_tblPriceRequestCurveValues_ForQuoteViewing] 
    ON [dbo].[tblPriceRequestCurveValues] ([DateForValue] ASC, [oid] ASC)
    INCLUDE ([CurveValue], [BTUFactor], [FuelShrink])
```

If you're always looking at data for a single `[oid]`, perhaps they need to flip to `[oid] ASC, [DateForValue] ASC`.

This is optimisation through the eye of a needle. Query optimisation usually needs to assess the query and execution plan as a whole.

Comment: To answer a few of your questions: This query pulls back ~30k records. It's the highest estimated cost operator in the plan. The entire query takes ~30 seconds to run. These columns that you're saying to include (that I was keying on) are being selected only, not filtered. With your suggested index, it still performs a key lookup on the clustered index.

Comment: @Jaxidian We're trying to understand the seek predicate. Hopefully your masking of the query won't mask that detail away.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I think the query I posted should explain the seek predicate - I think it's that INNER JOIN on that oid column.

Comment: Mark, based on your update, you don't think both oid and SomeID should be indexed, JUST SomeID?

Comment: Can't tell, too much obfuscation. You haven't included enough information to make that call. Simplest is going to be to try it and see.

Comment: Mark & Aaron, Thank you both for your patience with me. I guess I was mistakenly under the belief that Key Lookups on a 1M record table was bad and that an index scan was obviously much better. That appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @Jaxidian there is no "obviously much better" between <a> and <b>. There is often a whole lot of "it depends."

Comment: @AaronBertrand Indeed! Any suggested resources for me to better understand how I should tackle problems like this? I'm clearly lacking in some basics in understanding indexes and execution plans.

Comment: As a starting point, looking at execution plans in [Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) can be a lot more enlightening than in Management Studio. I point out how some of these issues are [highlighted in a demo kit I wrote last year](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/plan-explorer-3-0-demo-kit) (which you can also use for learning the tool to some degree). *Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.* May also want to grab Grant Fritchey's free e-book: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sql-server-execution-plans

Comment: Thanks, @AaronBertrand. I assume even the free version of SQL Sentry >> SSMS? I'm far too ignorant to know whether or not to purchase the Pro version. I'll check out that book as well.

Comment: When you download Plan Explorer, you can choose to just use the free version, or you can enable the Pro features for a 15 day trial. Use the free version for a week, and be conscious of the pro features (which are described at that link). Then think about whether those features might have been useful to you as you've been using the tool. Then you can enable the Pro features and evaluate them for 15 days, at which point it is quite simple to turn them off - or, if you like those features, to buy the Pro version (and entering a license at that point is simple too).